# Warning: move_uploaded_file [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

```
$target_path = "/public_html/user_images/";
//$target_path = realpath(user_images(getcwd()))

$targetpath = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$target_path = $target_path . $targetpath; 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
//echo "Image".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been successfully uploaded.";
$user_img = $target_path;
```

Comment: Look at your code and very carefully. What do you think it's trying to do?

Comment: You should add more information about your question! Is the directory exist? What is the directory permission? etc...

Answer (score 1):

The leading `/` slash takes you all the way to the root of your server. You need to either use the full path (which on your server might be e.g. `/home/yourdomain.com/public_html/images/`, or otherwise a path that is relative to the script you're running, e.g. `'../images/'` if your upload script were in `./public_html/codes/`, or simply `'./images/` if your script is in `./public_html/`.

- You also need to make sure that the folder has the correct permissions to write to it.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.